# El modal me carga el unicamente el primer ID

Tags: php, css, laravel, bootstrap

estoy haciendo un proyecto en Laravel y al cargar el modal dentro de un foreach para cargar los botones del eliminar me pasa siempre el mismo id por parametro. Pero cuando no uso el modal y uso el enlace directamente me funcciona a la perfeccion.

```
@if(count($categories)>0)
        @foreach($categories as $category)
        <a href="{{route('category.edit', ['id' => $category->id])}}" class="text-secondary mr-3">Editar</a>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <a href="{{route('category.delete', ['id' => $category->id])}}" class="text-danger">Borrar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="card mb-5 line">

            <h3 class="text-center">{{$category->name}}</h3>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        @else
        <p>Todavía no hay ninguna categoría creada. ¿A qué esperas para <a href="{{route('category.create')}}">crearlas</a>?</p>
        @endif
```

Editado con toda la información del blade

Comment: Considera leer [ask] y colocar un [mcve] desde el cual podamos evaluar el problema que mencionas

Comment: Lo siento si no se ha entendido @BetaM El caso es que estoy haciendo una vista que lista todas las categorias existentes con su boton para editar y borrar categorias respectivamente. Sin colocar el modal me funciona a la perfección, pero colocando éste el enlace que lleva el botón de borrar me coge siempre el ID de la primera categoría listada en lugar del ID de cada categoría

Comment: Sí @porloscerros Ψ No me di cuenta al mandarlo que tenia el codigo incompleto (disculpas) ya lo edité. es tal como dices. ¿Como puedo solucionarlo? gracias.

Comment: Sin javascript, puedes asignar un id dinámico a cada modal, pero si tienes muchos elementos en `$categories`, resultaría en un html larguísimo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

estas asignando el mismo id a todos los modales que se rederizan en el loop, para este caso como el id del modal es id="myModal" para todos, la solución es asignar un id dinamico a cada modal e igual al target asi

```html
@if(count($categories)>0)
@foreach($categories as $category)
<a href="{{route('category.edit', ['id' => $category->id])}}" class="text-secondary mr-3">Editar</a>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-{{$category->id}}">Open
    Modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal-{{$category->id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <a href="{{route('category.delete', ['id' => $category->id])}}" class="text-danger">Borrar</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card mb-5 line">
    <h3 class="text-center">{{$category->name}}</h3>
</div>
@endforeach
@else
<p>Todavía no hay ninguna categoría creada. ¿A qué esperas para <a href="{{route('category.create')}}">crearlas</a>?
</p>
@endif
```

Comment: Hola, he probado a hacerlo de esta manera pero al cambiar el ID del modal por el ID + {{$category->id}} el modal ya no se lanza y no abre.

Comment: Hola @porloscerros Ψ arreglado. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes compartir la solución para que alguno que tenga el mismo problema pueda solucionarlo, saludos